# How to display buy/sell signal only once, instead of getting it on every bar?

Tags: pine-script

I am working on the below code- the problem is that I am getting a Buy/Sell signal on every bar. How do I remove it from every bar and get the signal only once it gets triggered? Code is below

---

```
study(title="Humble LinReg Candles", shorttitle="LinReg Candles ", format=format.price, max_labels_count=100, precision=4, overlay=true)

signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 200, defval = 11)
sma_signal = input(title="Simple MA (Signal Line)", type=input.bool, defval=true)

lin_reg = input(title="Lin Reg", type=input.bool, defval=true)
linreg_length = input(title="Linear Regression Length", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 200, defval = 11)

bopen = lin_reg ? linreg(open, linreg_length, 0) : open
bhigh = lin_reg ? linreg(high, linreg_length, 0) : high
blow = lin_reg ? linreg(low, linreg_length, 0) : low
bclose = lin_reg ? linreg(close, linreg_length, 0) : close

r = bopen < bclose

signal = sma_signal ? sma(bclose, signal_length) : ema(bclose, signal_length)

plotcandle(r ? bopen : na, r ? bhigh : na, r ? blow: na, r ? bclose : na, title="UpCandle", color=#19968c, wickcolor=#19968c, bordercolor=#19968c, editable= true)
plotcandle(r ? na : bopen, r ? na : bhigh, r ? na : blow, r ? na : bclose, title="DownCandle", color=#b12a72, wickcolor=#b12a72, bordercolor=#b12a72, editable= true)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Buy Sell Signals
buySignal = (r ? bopen : na) and (r ? bhigh : na) and (r ? blow: na) and (r ? bclose : na)
sellSignal = (r ? na : bopen) and (r ? na : bhigh) and (r ? na : blow) and (r ? na : bclose)

plotshape(buySignal, title="Buy", text="B", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.normal, color=#24c491, textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(sellSignal, title="Sell", text="S", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.normal, color=#DA1D81, textcolor=color.white)

alertcondition(buySignal, title="LG Buy", message="Buy")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="LG Sell", message="Sell")
```

---

I've tried changing the conditions, but am not able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `buySignal` and `sellSignal` conditions are `true` on multiple bars.

You can have two `var` flags to see if you are already in a buy or sell position.

Add these as an additional conditoin to your `buySignal` and `sellSignal` so they would only be `true` if you are not already in a position.

```
var is_buy = false
var is_sell = false

buySignal = not is_buy and (r ? bopen : na) and (r ? bhigh : na) and (r ? blow: na) and (r ? bclose : na)
sellSignal = not is_sell and (r ? na : bopen) and (r ? na : bhigh) and (r ? na : blow) and (r ? na : bclose)

is_buy := sellSignal ? false : buySignal ? true : is_buy    // Update the flag
is_sell := buySignal ? false : sellSignal ? true : is_sell  // Update the flag
```